# Reset as I/O pin

Tags: arduino-ide, interrupt, reset

I'm looking to minimise the parts count and the power consumption as much as possible and I was wondering if is it possible to store a variable or execute a method when the 'reset' button is pressed?

<strike>I didn't find any docs or hints regarding this.</strike>

In theory, can it be done with an interrupt?

#### Edit

In a further research Atmel shows, that if you burn the 'RSTDISBL' fuse (still in theory for me) you can get hold of the reset button by transforming it in a I/O pin with "special" electric characteristics:

[image: Atmega 382 reset short description focus]

Also, if you look at the schematic the reset pin shows that it has what it needs to be an I/O pin:

[image]

I say in theory because I really don't know if arduino has the required constellation for this capability and if it comes whit the fuses already burned.

Comment: The `MCUSR` register shows whether there was an external reset (`EXTRF` bit). But I don't see how you can save power with this. I do see how you could use this instead of needing a button.

Comment: Well... MCUSR / EXTRF info in particular would not help a power save, but the answer to what I've asked will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several possibilities here.

One is detecting state after reset and acting on it.  One of the reasons you might do that would be to shut the processor down all but completely, and let the reset wake it back up.

Another would be to program the reset disable fuse and repurpose it as an I/O pin - of course if you do that, you can only then reprogram the chip if you have implement working functionality to get back to the bootloader (or similar), or if you use a high voltage programmer.

These are in the category of things which make development a lot more difficult, but are sometimes worthwhile as they let you squeeze a little more capability out of the hardware.  If you are just starting a design, you might consider a different chip instead - but if you have existing boards or design investment, and this lets you get the last little bit of needed capability from it, it is possible.

Comment: Wait ... What do you mean by a high voltage programmer ?

Comment: High Voltage Parallel Programming is described in sections 25.6 & 25.7 of the ATmega48/88/168/328p data sheet.  It involves using a ~12v signal on the reset pin, which allows overcoming fuse settings that might prevent other sorts of programming.  You can buy HVPP programmers from Atmel and others.